# MySQL optimize multiple inner joins

Tags: mysql, join

Probably that is the laziest mySQL query on the planet. I don't pretend to be an expert on this topic - I rely on the community to support.

I have two tables that I need to run in a query. One table has to be inner joined on itself to extract two ends of the link and then need to use the second table to extract the geographical coordinates. Not sure which one has to be done first. Some geography cutting will be required - but that is probably a question for another day.

The filtering should be done on FREQUENCY field and LONG/LAT box. But most importantly, columns of the same table DEVICE_DETAILS must be joined together to convert from:

Side A,,,,

Side B,,,,

TO:

Side A, Side B,,,,,

join on statement should explain this better:

The query is:

```
SELECT T.EFL_SYSTEM AS TX_EFL_SYSTEM,
          T.SITE_ID AS TX_SITE_ID,
          T.FREQUENCY AS TX_FREQUENCY, 
          T.DEVICE_TYPE AS TX_DEVICE_TYPE,
          T.EIRP AS TX_EIRP,
          T.LONGITUDE AS TX_LON,
          T.LATITUDE AS TX_LAT,
          R.EFL_SYSTEM AS RX_EFL_SYSTEM,
          R.SITE_ID AS RX_SITE_ID,
          R.FREQUENCY AS RX_FREQUENCY,
          R.DEVICE_TYPE AS RX_DEVICE_TYPE,
          R.EIRP AS RX_EIRP,
          ST.LONGITUDE,
          ST.LATITUDE,
          SR.LONGITUDE,
          SR.LATITUDE
  FROM DEVICE_DETAILS T
  INNER JOIN DEVICE_DETAILS R ON (T.EFL_SYSTEM=R.EFL_SYSTEM) AND (T.FREQUENCY=R.FREQUENCY) AND (T.DEVICE_TYPE != R.DEVICE_TYPE)
  INNER JOIN SITE ST ON T.SITE_ID = ST.SITE_ID
  INNER JOIN SITE SR ON R.SITE_ID = SR.SITE_ID
  WHERE T.FREQUENCY > 7425000000 AND T.FREQUENCY < 7525000000 AND R.FREQUENCY > 7425000000 AND R.FREQUENCY < 7525000000 AND T.DEVICE_TYPE = 'T';
```

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `SITE` (
    `SITE_ID` VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
    `LATITUDE` DECIMAL(18,14) NOT NULL,
    `LONGITUDE` DECIMAL(18,14) NOT NULL,
    `NAME` VARCHAR(1023) NOT NULL,
    `STATE` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `LICENSING_AREA_ID` INT(3) NOT NULL,
    `POSTCODE` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    `SITE_PRECISION` VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
    `ELEVATION` INT(5) NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

For the DEVICE_DETAILS table; missing some fields but these are the basic ones. There are no primary keys probably because I do CSV bulk import every morning. I think I have to optimize this part as well at a later stage

```
+--------------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                          | Type           | Null | Key | Default |    Extra|
+--------------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SDD_ID                         | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| FREQUENCY                      | bigint(20)     | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| BANDWIDTH                      | int(15)        | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| CARRIER_FREQ                   | bigint(20)     | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| EMISSION                       | varchar(63)    | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| DEVICE_TYPE                    | varchar(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| TRANSMITTER_POWER              | int(20)        | NO   |     | NULL    ||
| SITE_ID                        | varchar(31)    | NO   |     | NULL    |||
| EFL_SYSTEM                     | varchar(63)    | NO   |     | NULL    ||
+--------------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Any feedback or comment appreciated in that regard.

Questions:

1- Are these multiple INNER JOINS good practice? what other options are there optimize it
2- I use INFILE importation (everyday) from CSV; and I can not play with the source format. Can I still add indexes? does it impact the importation? anything else needed to optimize the index approach?
3- I can add filter on the SITE table by specifying Long/Lat rectangle boundary - will that help optimize the operation? where shall I add these conditions in my query

Note: My SITE table is around 11.5MB and DEVICE_DETAILS is around 232.8 MB. I have 8GB of RAM and 8 threads processor.

Comment: Can you clarify your specific problem/question?

Comment: Is my joining approach above appropriate for what I'm trying to achieve? can this be optimized? Currently this query is taking forever.

Comment: You need to allow MySQL to fully utilize resources of the computer it runs at. That means it needs to be **configured** because default config shipped with it is there to make it work on really, really old computer. Your queries are taking forever because you haven't done a thing for MySQL to work faster. Basically, writing the query properly, indexing and what not is just half of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Kindly appreciated. I did optimize `query_cache_limit       = 10M
query_cache_size        = 512M
# yahya added
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4048M` its relaxing to know that the query is OK. I'm also looking to add Lat/Long filtering..any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely optimize by adding INDEXES to your tables.

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Off the top of my head, and without seeing your data (which is quite important), I would suggest to add indexes for your main WHERE and JOIN clauses:

```
ALTER TABLE DEVICE_DETAILS ADD INDEX FREQUENCY (FREQUENCY), ADD INDEX DEVICE_TYPE (DEVICE_TYPE), ADD INDEX SITE_ID (SITE_ID);
ALTER TABLE SITE ADD INDEX SITE_ID (SITE_ID);
```

Also, I think you may have a bug (that's not for optimization) - should the JOIN to ST have this ON clause:

```
ON T.SITE_ID = ST.SITE_ID
```

Instead of:

```
ON R.SITE_ID = ST.SITE_ID
```

Comment: Does my query filter by FREQUENCY first and then does the JOINING? Also do you think I better off break it down into multiple queries so mySQL will resolve one first and then address the other?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention; I'm importing the data on daily basis from csv files using  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. I can not control the columns in the CSV files. Will adding indexes effect the importation due to format mismatch or something?

Comment: Adding the indexes made this crazy fast!!! Duration for 1 query: 0.063 sec. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: @yahyakhaled sorry for not logging in for a while - glad it helped!